# Conditional evaluation of knitr chunks with Rstudio "Run" button

Tags: rstudio, knitr, r-markdown

I am using conditional evaluation using the `eval` option in the chunk header. If I write `eval=FALSE` in the header, the chunk is not evaluated when I knit the document, and also not when I use the **Run All (Ctrl+Alt+R)** from the Rstudio menu.

The problem arises when I try to provide `eval` with a variable, e.g. the example below:

````
```{r setup}
ev_cars = TRUE
ev_pressure = FALSE
```

## First chunk

```{r cars, eval=ev_cars}
summary(cars)
```

## Second chunk

```{r pressure, echo=FALSE, eval = ev_pressure}
plot(pressure)
```
````

In this example, when I run knitr, then the first chunk is evaluated and the second chunk is not (because `ev_pressure=FALSE`). However, when I try to run using he **Run All (Ctrl+Alt+R)** from the Rstudio menu, both chunks are evaluated.

Is there a way to overcome this issue?

I am using Rstudio v 1.1

All the best,

Gil

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: {*The chunk options are only used when you `knit`. The `Run All` command does not knit the document but execute what is inside chunks, without reading chunks arguments.*} This is not totally true, indeed, if `eval` is set to FALSE or TRUE, it is taken into account.
*{Thus, a}* way to add options like not executing code inside chunks when running `Run All` would be to do it in the old way with an `if` inside the chunk.

````
```{r setup}
ev_cars = TRUE
ev_pressure = FALSE
```

## First chunk

```{r cars}
if (ev_cars) {
  summary(cars)
}
```

## Second chunk

```{r pressure, echo=FALSE}
if (ev_pressure) {
  plot(pressure)
}
```
````

The code is then heavier in this way. But if you use `Run All`, why not directly knit it ?

Comment: Thank you Sébastien. There is some chunk argument evaluation, because when `eval=F` the chunk is not executed with Run. I gave the **Run All** case, just as an understandable and reproducible example. In real life I evaluate up to certain points in the script.

Comment: True, I did not realize that. If it is TRUE or FALSE, the `eval` argument is taken into account, but if it is a parameter, it is not.